# At most how many distinct unit vectors can be selected in $\mathbb R^n$ such that from any three of them, at least two are orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, solution-verification, extremal-combinatorics

> Let $n$ be a positive integer. At most how many distinct unit vectors can be selected in $\mathbb R^n$ such that from any three of them, at least two are orthogonal?

Clearly we can achive value $2n$ if we take vectors $\pm e_i$, for $i=1,2,...,n$, where $\{e_1,e_2,...e_n\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb R^n$.

Call this set $S$. Let's prove that it can have no more than $2n$ elements with strong induction. Suppose $|S|\geq 2n+1$. Then clearly exists two vectors $a,b$ in $S$ that are not colinear nor orthogonal. Let $A=\{v\in S;\;v\cdot a=0 \}$ and $B=\{v\in S;\;v\cdot b=0 \}$. Then each vector $v$ is in set $A$ or in set $B$ (or both). Let $\bar A$ and $\bar B$ be span of $A$ respectively $B$. If $|A|=p$ and $|B|=q$ then  $\dim \bar A\leq p/2$ and $\dim\bar B\leq q/2$ since $A$ and $B$ are the same type of set as $S$ is. $$p/2+q/2 \geq \dim \bar A + \dim \bar B  \geq \dim (\bar A+\bar B)  $$
Since $\bar A+\bar B \leq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ we have $p/2+q/2 \leq n-1$ so $p+q+2\leq 2n$ and we are done.

---

Well I have a feeling that this is wrong. Some better idea how to solve this?

Comment: It looks correct. I think you mean $A = \{v \in S | v \cdot a = 0\}$ where $S$ is the set of $2n+1$ vectors.

Comment: Now: What's the largest $S$ so that for any $r$-subset of them, $k$ of them are orthogonal?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear. I mean, what's the size of the largest $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that has the property that for any subset $T \subseteq S$ of size $r$ there is a subset $U \subseteq T$ of size $k$ with all vectors of $U$ being orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Perhaps you should post this as a new question. I suppose it can be done by similar procedure as here when $r=3$ and $k=2$. @JairTaylor

Comment: Anyway, I was hoping for more combinatorial solution to this one, like defining a graph where two vectors = nodes are conected iff they are orthogonal. Then there is no $K_3$ in complement... @JairTaylor

Comment: Funny, I had precisely the same thought, but could not make it work.

Comment: I believe your proof has a couple of gaps ("clearly", "same type set as $S$", "$\bar{A}+\bar{B}\leq R^{n-1}$")

Comment: What is problem with same type of $S$? @Bananach

Comment: Why does the two-out-of-three property imply something about the dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannot delete this answer because it is accepted. But it's wrong

Comment: This is very nice proof. Thanks! But I still doubt my proof is correct.

Comment: Why is $x\bot a$ **and** $x\bot b$?

Comment: @Bananach $x \perp a$ means that $x$ is orthogonal to $a$.

Comment: I get that, but the property of $S$ implies that $x\bot a$ **or** $x\bot b$

Comment: @Bananach Ah, I see what you mean now.  Looking at it again, that is incorrect - it should be "or". Right now I can't think of a way to fix it but maybe I think about it more later.

Answer (score 1):

Can someone explain to me how can I assure $x$ has to be orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$? I know by property of $S$ that $x$ has to be orthogonal to at least one of them, but not necessarily to both.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the previous answer? You should ask for clarification under that answer instead of posting your question as an answer -- Stackexchange is not a forum.

Comment: Mathematically, I think your objection is valid and I asked for clarification on your behalf

Comment: Sorry. I didn't have many points to make a comment until now, but thanks